# Euclidean distance between two set of 3D points

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor, euclidean-distance

How can I find the nearest points of two set of 3D points(with different number,set1 includes 400 points and set2 includes 2000 points) and then find the Euclidean distance between set1 and result from first part of the question?

Comment: share your code... hint is using `knnsearch` and `pdist2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) to compute **all** distances and then pick the minimal distance.

```
allDist = squareform( pdist2( set1, set2 ) );
[minDist nni] = min( allDist, [], 2 );
```

Now `minDist` holds the minimal distance of each point in `set1` to its nearest-neighbor (`set2(nni)`).

**EDIT:**
for low dimensional points (3 in this example) it should be more efficient to look at k-NN algorithms, as proposed in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15094400/1714410).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [`k-Nearest Neighbors (kNN)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) search?